# Hive: python UDF gives “Hive Runtime Error while closing operators”

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, udf

I have a requirement to convert few date formats and manipulate to boolean condition based on some business logic.

However I am failing issue while calling the python script from Hive. Below is the script I have written to convert the date format for sample 1 column:

```
import sys

def getYearMonthFromStringDate(dt):
    year=0
    month=0
    try:
        ss=dt.split('-')
        year=ss[0]
        month=ss[1]
    except ValueError:
        print "Error parsing date string %s" %dt
    return int(year)*100+int(month)

for line in sys.stdin:
    tempArr=line.split('\t')
    accountgl0s=tempArr[0]
    agl0 = getYearMonthFromStringDate(accountgl0s)
    output_list = [accountgl0s, ag10]
    print '\t'.join(output_list)
```

I added the file in distributed cache using the following command:

```
add file /folder/date.py
```

Now, I am calling this Python function on col `accountgl0s` of my hive table using Transform as follows:

```
Input column accountgl0s = '2016-10-01'

select transform(accountgl0) using 'python date.py' as (accountgl0s,agl0) from sample;
```

My expected output should be `2016-10-01 201610`. But I am getting the error below:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:199)
        ... 8 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20003 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Comment: above these error message, there is a URL in output message  like  Starting Job = job_1480642810315_083110, Tracking URL = http://hadoop-test15.int.xxxxxx.com:8088/proxy/application_148012122315_081130/ ，visit this url and you can find  information about python error message .

Comment: Why are you writing a custom python script to split a string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change type your variable to float when you wanna compute number:

```
f_accountgl0s = float(accountgl0s)
```